# Not wanted JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS in spring batch

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing

I am facing a strange situation. I am developping a springboot app that uses spring-batch to handle some jobs. The thing is that for some reason on my dB an aditional row is being inserted in the `batch_job_execution_params`. But this only happens if the springboot application runs with any arguments (args).

Any ideas of why this happens ?

Comment: Each time you run your job and pass some parameters, a record is inserted in the parameters table. What is strange with that?

Comment: Well, what I really need is not to insert the parameters passed via arguments, but only those that I command via java code, for example:  JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("timestamp",System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters(); How can I do that ?